# Difficulty in managing URL Paths

Tags: asp.net, url, path

Managing url paths can be a real pain in ASP.NET.  AbsolutePath vs RelativePath vs etc. drives me crazy.  I find that many solutions require the user to edit web.config element to include the correct subfolder path; ex.

Website Root: http://www.domain.com
Web.config setting: /

Website Root: http://www.domain.com/blog
web.config setting: /blog/

Is there a way to properly handle this without having to make changes to the web.config?

Comment: I /blog configured as a virtual app in IIS or just a sub directory of the web app?

Comment: This would be the case for a virtual app, such as running BlogEngine.NET under your parent domain site.  Ex.  www.domain.com/blog would map to your blogengine application folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Request.ApplicationPath.  A reference of usage is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.applicationpath.aspx).

This way your images folder, for example, will be Request.ApplicationPath + "/images/";

Answer (score 1):

I think [Rick's blog entry](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/154812.aspx) helps solve some of my problems...